# Double button hit

Tags: android, eclipse, button

hey I'm creating an app with two switches on it that change the background of the xml.

however, if the user touches button 1 then 2 I want it to change the background from pic1 to pic2(on first button hit) then pic4(on second button hit)

but if the user touches button 2 then 1 I want it to change the background from pic1 to pic3(on first button hit) then pic4(on second button hit)

at the moment this is my script;

```
package com.jamie.game;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class level2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button button1;
    View targetView;
    Button button2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level2);
    targetView = (View)findViewById(R.id.level2);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    button1.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener)this);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    button2.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener)this);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(v.getId()==(R.id.button1)){
            targetView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic2);
            if(v.getId()==(R.id.button2)){
            targetView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic4);
    }else
        if(v.getId()==(R.id.button2)){
                targetView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic3);
            if(v.getId()==(R.id.button2)){
            targetView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic4);

        }
    }


}
```

but all this does is alternate between pic2 and pic3 on button clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to create a variable to store the ID of the button that was just clicked. Then, when you receive the next click, you can just check this variable to know if the sequence matches your condition. For example, if you click the first button - store its ID in an `int lastChecked` variable, then when you click the second button - you should whether `lastChecked` equals to the first button ID. If it is - then you can run your `View` changing code. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks i created a variable called 'button' and changed it when the buttons were clicked then added more if statements and it worked great